# In the Circle of Magic Series, what is the nature of Lark and Rosethorn's relationship to one another?

Tags: young-adult, tamora-pierce, circle-universe

I was reading a list of fantasy novels that included queer protagonists and it was revealed that in later books, Daja is in a same-sex relationship.  It also stated that earlier books "feature a sympathetic lesbian couple."  I can only assume this was a reference to Lark and Rosethorn, but I never got that vibe.  However, I don't have a copy of the books nearby to check.  Has this ever been officially confirmed?  Was it alluded to or hinted at and I missed it because I was twelve?

Comment: I'm fairly sure in at least some cases their speech patterns indicate they're a couple - I remember when I was much younger, sometimes I'd think maybe Lark was male _because_ of how Lark and Rosethorn spoke to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The Will of the Empress*, Chapter 13, page 347 in my copy.  Daja just followed Rizu somewhere, and Sandry got a sudden burst of Daja's emotions (bolding mine, passage from Sandry's point of view):

> "Shaved ice would be wonderful, thank you," she said.  She waved the
>   fan hurriedly, trying to cool the scarlet blush she felt rising on her
>   cheeks.  Once he was gone and she didn't have to work to talk to him,
>   she put up more blocks on her connection to her sister, trying to keep
>   it open without knowing anything of what Daja was up to now.  Only when
>   she had reduced it to the merest thread did she lean back in her chair
>   and close her eyes.
>
> I don't think she knew, thought Sandry.  Or if she did, **she thought
>   she was more like Rosethorn, interested in women and men**.  I know
>   she's mentioned boys, once or twice, but never girls.  Thinking of
>   Risu, Sandry added, Or women.

And in the following chapter, on page 359 in my book - this is from Briar's perspective, Daja just invited him into her room.  Bolding mine:

> Briar at her smiled knowingly and glanced at the open bedroom door. 
>   Rizu stood there, wrapping a sheet around herself.  Her long curls
>   were free of their pins and dangled to her waist.  The sheet only
>   enhanced her buxom figure.
>
> Briar raised his eyebrows at Rizu, then looked at Daja, who scratched
>   at the floor with a bare toe.  "Well, that explains more than it
>   doesn't," Briar remarked.  He told himself, Now I know why I was sure
>   Rizu was never interested in me, or any man.  **"Daja, why didn't you
>   say you're a *nisamohi*?" he asked, using the Tradertalk word for a
>   woman who loved other women.  "What with Lark and Rosethorn, did you
>   think we cared?"**

So yes, at least in this book, it was confirmed that Lark and Rosethorn were in a same-sex sexual relationship.  Hints/clues/confirmation, I doubt were in the previous books - those were about the main four when they were much younger.

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't gotten to "Will of the Empress" yet.  Guess patience would have paid off.

Comment: @AdeleC  Oops, sorry about that.  I had the impression from the question you did read it and just didn't remember.

Comment: No worries.  I had read something indicating that Daja was a lesbian, which motivated me to start rereading the Circle Opens, and it alluded to Lark and Rosethorn.  So no major spoilers.

Comment: To add to this, due to events in Battle Magic, we see that they also have a somewhat open relationship.

Comment: @AshleyNunn La-La-La-La Not Liiiisteniiiing, don't have the booook yeeett....

Comment: @Izkata Sorry for the minor spoiler :(

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning: Since the original Circle quartet was published by Scholastic (hence in schools/for kids), they probably wouldn't have approved of making it explicit, so it was perfectly possible to think they were just sharing a flat (they did, after all, have separate rooms.) Tammy's readers grew up as her characters did, so I think that's probably why she was more open about it in later books.